# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions error in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

i am using React Router v4 in which i create a route file after creating a router path it gives a =n error as i mention of Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions.
i try my best to solve it but cannot as i am beginner in React that's why.
Kindly solve this issue.

here is my code of router.js file.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Link

} from 'react-router-dom';
import App from '../App';

const CustomRoute = () => {

    <Router> 
               <Route path="/" component={App} />

       </Router> 
}

export default CustomRoute;
```

Comment: Show us your App component, please.

Comment: The problem is specific to JS, not React.

Comment: I'm so used to seeing () => () I over looked the {}

Answer (score 2):

Function component should return a value and it doesn't. Linter error reflects that.

It should be either:

```
const CustomRoute = () => {
    return <Router> 
           <Route path="/" component={App} />
    </Router> 
}
```

Or:

```
const CustomRoute = () => (
    <Router> 
           <Route path="/" component={App} />
    </Router> 
)
```